# Text Alignment problem

Tags: line-breaking, languages, hyphenation

I am having a problem with the alignment in my pdf. The pdf is compiled with Xelatex. Some words instead of being separated with a "-" and continue at the bottom line are written whole in the upper line and thus they extend more than they should normally leading to a bad result to the reader's eye, as they don't respect the right margin of the page. Any possible ideas? I am not speaking of a mathematical formula, which can't be separated, I am speaking of a simple word that normally should have been separated with a "-" and continue at the next line. In my text, there are more than 1 languages if that helps. Any ideas appreciated, feel free to ask more if question is not specific enough.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (e.g., whether you use the `babel` package and/or the `\hypenation` command).

Comment: @lockstep It is a bit difficult, because for the first time this occurs after the page 14 of my pdf. How can I attach the pdf here? I am new here so I don't really know how.

Comment: Attached PDFs aren't useful to reconstruct your problem. Instead, in a copy (!) of your actual document, remove the first 14 pages. If the bad line break is still present, you now have a small example. Also, try to remove packages that aren't essential to the problem.

Comment: Please, show at least a paragraph where the problem appears, telling what's the involved word. It's also important to know what languages you're using; is the problematic word in a different language than the main one?

Comment: You can try with `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and then `\setdefaultlanguage{<lang1>}`, `\setotherlanguages{<lang2>,<lang3>,...}`, and then switch to the appropriate languages using `\text<lang>{...}` or `\begin{<lang>}...\end{<lang>}`

Comment: Problem is that together with my pdf I have also a .cls meaning that it wastly surpasses the 512 characters allowed to be written here. What do you propose in this case to show you an example?

Comment: As it stands, this is 'too localized' as there is not an example or any of the other things we need to help. Request reopening after an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for an comment:

Just to give you an idea how you can build a MWE have a look to this one (compile this with `pdflatex`):

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76131/text-alignment-problem
%compile this MWE with pdflatex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % utf-8 input encoding
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          % Fontencription
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}       % German ä and ü
%\usepackage{microtype}            % use always
 \usepackage{showframe}            % to show frame

%\hyphenation{Donau-dampf-schiffs-kapitäns-mütze}
%\hyphenation{Do-nau-dampf-schiffs-ka-pi-täns-müt-ze}
\begin{document}
To create some hyphenation errors we use the German word 
%To create some hyphenation errors we use the long German word 
Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze 
Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze 
Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze 
Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze 
Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze Do\-nau\-dampf\-schiffs\-ka\-pi\-täns\-müt\-ze 
Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze Donaudampfschiffskapitänsmütze 
\end{document}
```

Play with the included `%` signs to change the behavior of the `tex` document. Change this MWE (I do not run XeLaTeX so I don't know) and copy your **relevant** macros into it to show us, what you are doing in your thesis.

Comment: Ok thanks but one question. Pdflatex seems to understand even without hyphenation instructions where to divide words. On the other hand Xelatex doesn't hyphenate words correctly even when given those instructions. Isn't that strange behavior? I should find an equivalent of microtype for Xelatex I think

Comment: If everything fails, you can use `\sloppy` before the paragraph where you have words that goes in the margin and `\fussy`  after the paragraph. Inter word spacing  will be less than optimal for such paragraphs.